# How do I use "GET users/search" from twitter v1.1 API?

Tags: node.js, twitter

I am making a bot and want to search users that have ".eth" in their names. I have not been able to do that using Twitter Api v2 and the the only endpoint I found that can be used is available only in V1.1.

Can someone guide me how I can do this?

I have tried looking all over the web and even chatGPT but to no avail. I only have limited v1.1 access.